# Get 12 noon timestamp of current date in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want timestamp of current date as reference 12 noon. 
We can get current timestamp like

```
[[NSDate Date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

But i want timestamp for 12 Noon for today.Thanks in advance

Comment: Not for specific timezone , But timezone of device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just used this . This will give you 12 noon timestamp. Because it's calculated as per [NSDate Date] , it will give you on the base of device's timezone.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *today12Noon = [calendar dateBySettingHour:12 minute:0 second:0 ofDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

double dif = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - [today12Noon timeIntervalSince1970];
double timeStampWithReference12Noon = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - dif ;
```

Comment: It's working. 
I checked timestamp online after result , it's exactly what i need.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Date2 to the current time in your device.

```
NSDate *date1 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2010-01-01 00:00:00 +0000"];
NSDate *date2 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2010-02-03 00:00:00 +0000"];

NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];

int numberOfDays = secondsBetween / 86400;

NSLog(@"There are %d days in between the two dates.", numberOfDays);
```